# How to hide ImageView on AppBar like Facebook Profile?

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout, nestedscrollview

I want to do a Profile Activity with an appbar with coordinator layout  Facebook like, but I don't know how to hide the views when the appbar is scrolling up and I get my view stuck behind the toolbar

What I want:
Full profile  -> fading out when scrolling -> action bar when full scrolled

[image]
[image]
[image]

What I have:

[image]
[image]

I used the scrolling activity example from Android Studio and edited to this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ScrollingActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_proflie"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">


              </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
            <LinearLayout
                android:weightSum="5"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="12dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img_profile_pic"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:scaleType="centerInside"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_profile"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_alias"
                        android:textSize="28sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_name"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_district"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:id="@+id/rlt_player_status"
                        android:background="@drawable/profile_box"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                        android:paddingRight="12dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txt_profile_status"
                            android:text="@string/txt_profile_status_unknown"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="11sp"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_edit_profile" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: look at this: https://github.com/flavienlaurent/poppyview/blob/master/poppyview-library/src/com/fourmob/poppyview/NotifyingScrollView.java  and then  implement ` NotifyingScrollView.OnScrollChangedListener  `

Comment: check out this example project: https://github.com/liuguangqiang/AndroidDesignSupportSample

Comment: Still can't make it works, I can´t find how to implement those examples in the scenario I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find how to fix this via XML, just replacing the layout where it should be, in the `CollpasingBarLayout` not in the `toolBar`.

So this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ScrollingActivity">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_proflie"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

            <LinearLayout
                android:weightSum="5"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="12dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img_profile_pic"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:scaleType="centerInside"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_profile"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_alias"
                        android:textSize="28sp"
                        android:text="JD"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_name"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:text="John Doe"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_district"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:text="Free Town"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        android:id="@+id/rlt_player_status"
                        android:background="@drawable/profile_box"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                        android:paddingRight="12dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txt_profile_status"
                            android:text="@string/txt_profile_status_unknown"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="11sp"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
              </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

And it looks like this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Utilize `AppBarLayout` offset to determine the alpha value of the view. Basically, that's what Facebook app does, fades the view in/out.

```
public class FadingViewOffsetListener implements AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener {
        private View mView;    
        public FadingViewOffsetListener(View view) {
            mView = view;
        }


        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
            verticalOffset = Math.abs(verticalOffset);
            float halfScrollRange = (int) (appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange() * 0.5f);
            float ratio = (float) verticalOffset / halfScrollRange;
            ratio = Math.max(0f, Math.min(1f, ratio));
            ViewCompat.setAlpha(mView, ratio);

        }
}
```

This will make your view fade in or out within total scroll range and half scroll range.

After that, just pass instance of this `OnOffsetChangedListener` implementation to your `AppBarLayout` using `addOnOffsetChangedListener()` method.

Comment: I will try this, if this help, sir, you'll have helped me a lot.

Comment: It totally works, but I found a better way to do it.